# Vaadin JPAContainer doesn't work

Tags: java, jpa, vaadin

I created a web app application like my work thesis. This application used the entire stack java EE 6: JPA2, EJB, JSF, RichFaces....

Now i'm trying to change the UI of my application from RichFaces to Vaadin. The first problems began with use of JPA container. i can't get a instance of entitymanager.

this is my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation=" http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="primary">

  <jta-data-source>java:jboss/VaadinDS</jta-data-source>

  <class>org.mypackage.entity.Utente</class>
  <class>org.mypackage.entity.Indirizzo</class>
  <class>org.mypackage.entity.Paese</class>

  <properties>
     <!-- Properties for Hibernate -->
     <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
     <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
  </properties>
 </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

this is my singelton class where i want to get the i instance of entitymanager

```
public class Utility {

private static EntityManager entityManager;

public Utility() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public static EntityManager getInstance(){

    if(entityManager == null)
        entityManager = JPAContainerFactory.createEntityManagerForPersistenceUnit("primary");

    return entityManager;

}
 }
```

but doesn't work , i showed always the followed error:

```
[com.vaadin.server.DefaultErrorHandler] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) : java.lang.NullPointerException
```

where i wrong?

Comment: Why are you using EJB and the EntityManager outside of a Session Bean? Maybe this helps: https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/jpacontainer.entityprovider.html

Answer (score 0):

Your persistence.xml file needs to have a dialect property

Also, you need 2 other things that the book of vaadin explain if you are using hibernate with the jpacontainer: The use of one entity manager per reqeust pattern and the use of hibernate lazy loading delegate on your entity provider. If you need more help, I'll keep updating this answer.